# Algorithm to Categorize sizes using Javascript or Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, logic

I need some help with this problem on a Web App to that I am working on for our Inventory management. So let me run you through the details:

- Every product has a size dimension in Width and Height (Lets call them sizeW and sizeH) and Area (just multiplication of the two dimensions)
- Every product needs to be categorized into a Size Category, let me list a few:
  50 x 100,
  80 x 150,
  100 x 170,
  150 x 200,
  ..... 12 categories in total
- The catch is that every product is not accurately made according to the Size Categories, so if a product is 55 x 96 or 44 x 105 then it will fall under the 50 x 100 category.

I need to write an algorithm which can categorize the item into the relevant category but taking into account such irregularities in various sizes. We don't want the user to manually input the category as we want to reduce the data entry time, but if the algorithm suggest something wrong or the product does not fit in standard categories then the user can takeover and change/add the category manually.

I would really appreciate if you guys can give ideas regarding this problem, the app is built using Rails on server-side and Javascript on the client-side. I would prefer if the solution is in Javascript and let the browser process the algorithm rather than put load on the server.

Thanks,

Umer

Comment: To me, this is not a technology-specific question, but rather a math/general CS question. The real work lies in figuring out the algorithm, after that the programming should be trivial.

Comment: Why 55 x 96 is represented as 50 x 100? Because it is the closest one?

Comment: please try to accurately describe your rule for deciding which category a product belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aspect ratios of the categories are all similar, I would go with the answer given by Kaeros. If, however, you have categories with dissimilar aspect ratios, say one category with dimensions 80 x 80 and another with dimensions 20 x 320, you could get some very odd misclassifications.

In this second case I would use the least squared distance between each category and the product size or, for a product P, the category C that minimizes:

(C.height - P.height)<sup>2</sup> + (C.width - P.width)<sup>2</sup>

With only 12 possibilities to compute it shouldn't take any time at all, though Kaeros's answer has the advantage of being able to precompute the areas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach really helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this (looking for areas). 
You can also optimize the search so it will not be linear.

```
var categories {
  names: ['50 x 100', '80 x 150', '100 x 170', '150 x 200'],
  areas: [5000, 12000, 17000, 30000],
  sizes: 4
}

function set_category(w, h) {
  var area = w * h;

  for(var i = 1; i < categories.sizes; i++) {
    var diff1 = 0, 
        diff2 = 0;

    if(area <= categories.areas[i]) {
      diff1 = categories.areas[i] - area;
      diff2 =  area - categories.areas[i-1];

      if(diff1 < diff2) return categories.names[i];
      return categories.names[i-1];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm. I tried it on several item but sometimes due to the range being very close to each other resulted in inaccurate selection. By just changing it to the least squared of distances resulted in much accurate selection of the category. Thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is classification. There are number of classification methods that you can use for solving this problem. Your choice will depend on number of features and number of samples. You should find implementation of Machine Learning algorithms for Ruby. You can use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html for implementing those or you can find existing ML library for Ruby such is [sci-kit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for Python.